# Why is the Ramsey`s theorem a generalization of the Pigeonhole principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, ramsey-theory

German Wikipedia states that the Ramsey`s theorem is a generalization of the Pigeonhole principle [source](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Ramsey)

But does not say why this is true. I am doing a presentation about the Ramsey theory and also wanna explain why this is true, but as not really an mathematician myself I can`t figure it out by myself.

So my question is:

*What is an easy explanation for the fact that the Ramsey`s theorem is a generalization of the Pigeonhole principle?*

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I never heard Ramsey's theorem called a **simplification** of the pigeonhole principle. I'd call it a **generalization**. Isn't that what "Verallgemeinerung" means?

Comment: That seems right, I have translated "Verallgemeinerung" the wrong way. Thanks for that input, have edited it!

Comment: Do you need an explanation of how Ramsey's theorem is a generalization of the pigeonhole principle, or does that seem clear?

Comment: Thats exaclty what I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pigeonhole principle states that for a given number of pigeons,  if only there are enough holes then at least one empty hole is guaranteed to exist.

Ramsey' s theorem states that if only there are enough vertices then at least one thingy (e.g., red or blue triangle) is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: I'd revise the summary of "pigeonhole principle" to say for a given number of holes, if there are enough pigeons (or other items), there will exist a hole with more than one pigeon/item.

Answer (score 9):

Ramsey's theorem, in general, says that for given $n, t, $ and $k$, there is a number $R$ (depending on $(n,t,k)$) such that for every $R$-element set $S$ and every $k$-coloring of the $t$-element subsets of $S$ $$f : S^{\{1,2,\ldots, t\}} \to \{1,2,\ldots, k\}$$ there is an $n$-element subset $S'\subset S$ such that $f$ is constant when restricted to the $t$-element subsets of $S'$.

The Ramsey theorem for graphs takes $S$ to be the set of vertices of an $R$-clique, and $t=2$; by coloring 2-sets of vertices we are coloring edges of the clique. $S'$ is then the $n$-vertex subgraph of $S$ whose edges are all the same color.

The pigeonhole principle takes $S$ to be some unstructured set and $t=1$. Then $f$ is a $k$-coloring of the $1$-sets of $S$ (that is, the elements) and the pigeonhole principle tells us that for any given $n$ and $k$, there is an $R(n, 1, k)$, namely $R=kn-k+1$, so that whenever $S$ has $R$ elements,  there must be an $n$-element subset $S'$ on which $f$ is constant.